# How to import ts and scss files from non-relative path in .net core 2.1 Angular 6 template

Tags: typescript, sass, path, visual-studio-2017, angular6

I have created a new `.net core 2.1` application using the `angular template`, and after that I've updated the project to use `Angular 6`.

*note the project is almost the same as the project that angular cli generates*

My project will have a lot of components and services, so instead of using relative paths I like to be able to use non-relative paths

### TypeScript

```
import { WeatherService } from '../../services/weather.service'
```

I wanted to have the ability to use non-relative path like:

```
import { WeatherService } from '@app-services/weather.service'
```

so I added

```
"baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@app-services/*": [ "src/app/services/*" ]
    },
```

into the `tsconfig.json`

the whole config:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@app-services/*": [ "src/app/services/*" ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

It's works as expected, I can import the service in every component, for instance:

```
import { WeatherService } from '@app-services/weather.service';
```

But I get this error when I run `ng build`:

> ERROR in app/components/home/home.component.ts(3,32): error TS2307:
>   Cannot find module '@app-services/weather.service'.

How to solve this ?

*Note: inside `ClientApp/src/` there is another extension of the `tsconfig` file i.e. `tsconfig.app.json`, but when I add the non-relative path there, the importing simply doesn't work, don't know why this is happening too*

---

### Scss

I have installed `node-sass` and I have changed all the `.css` files to be `.scss`, and besides that I added

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [ 
                "./src/common/"
              ]
```

inside `angular.json`

*inside the `common` folder I keep all the global scss files:*

```
common
 |
  - _images.scss
  - _colors.scss
```

Also, added this into the same file:

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "scss" // <<---
    }
  }
```

It works fine for relative paths:

```
@import '../../../common/_images.scss';
```

unfortunately, I get this error:

> Undeclared variable

when I import like this:

```
@import '_images';
```

**But**.. but, it works fine after build

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  import { WeatherService } from '~app-services/weather.service'
```

instead of this :

```
import { WeatherService } from '@app-services/weather.service'
```